# How to reinitialize tasks in ADA

Tags: task, ada, restart

I have a simple looking question:

I have a few tasks operating simultaneously in ADA. Together they create a simulation representing an election of an imaginary country. I'd like to restart the whole simulation if a certain condition occurs. So I want to abort every task, and restart them. How do I do this without recreating the tasks? I'm sure there's a nicer way but I can't seem to find it. By the way, the tasks are in an array. Thanks in advance!!

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

procedure Election is

type RandNum is new Integer range 1..100;

package RandInt is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(RandNum);
use RandInt;

task type Youngster;
task type DarkSide;

task type Guard;

NowVoting: Boolean := False;
YoungsterNum: Positive := 7;
DarkNum: Positive := 3;
G: Generator;

type PartyType is array (Positive range 1..3) of Natural;

task Place is
entry Vote(Num: in RandNum; Cheat: in Boolean);
end Place;

protected Collector is
procedure GoHome;
procedure GuardIn;
procedure GuardOut;
procedure Arrest;
function HowManyArrested return Natural;
function HowManyGuards return Natural;
function HowMany return Integer;
private
Home: Integer := 0;
Guards: Natural := 2;
Arrested: Natural := 0;
end Collector;

task body Place is
Party: PartyType := (0,0,0);
Guard1: Guard;
Guard2: Guard;
Votes: Natural := 0;
begin

Put_Line("-----------------------------------------------");
Put_Line("         A SZAVAZĂS KEZDETĂ‰T VESZI");
Put_Line("-----------------------------------------------");
while Collector.HowMany /= YoungsterNum and Collector.HowManyArrested /= DarkNum     loop


        accept Vote(Num: in RandNum; Cheat: in Boolean) do

            NowVoting := True;

            if Num < 33 then
                Party(1) := Party(1) + 1;
            elsif Num > 33 and Num < 66 then
                Party(2) := Party(2) + 1;
            else
                Party(3) := Party(3) + 1;
            end if;

            Votes := Votes + 1;

        delay 2.0;

            Put("IfjonctanĂˇcsok Intergalaktikus SzĂ¶vetsĂ©ge: ");
            Put_Line(Integer'Image(Party(1)));
            Put("ĹfelsĂ©ge LeghĹ±bb EllenzĂ©ke: ");
            Put_Line(Integer'Image(Party(2)));
            Put("Demokratikus EllenzĂ©k: ");
            Put_Line(Integer'Image(Party(3)));
            Put("Ă–sszesĂ­tve: ");
            Put_Line(Natural'Image(Votes));
            Put_Line("-----------------------------------------------");
            if Cheat then
                Put_Line("!!! C S A L Ă S !!!");
            end if;

            NowVoting := False;
        end;

end loop;


if (Votes-(YoungsterNum + DarkNum)) > ((YoungsterNum + DarkNum) / 20) then
    Put_Line("A szavazĂˇst meg kell ismĂ©telni!");
end if;

end Place;

task body Youngster is
Num: RandNum;
Success: Boolean := False;
Time: Natural := 0;
begin

Reset(G);
Num := Random(G);

while Success = False loop
while Time /= 6 and Success = False loop
    if NowVoting = False and (Collector.HowManyGuards = 2 
                          or Collector.HowManyGuards = 0) then
        Place.Vote(Num, False);
        Success := True;
        Collector.GoHome;
    else
        Time := Time + 1;
        delay 1.0;
    end if;

end loop;

if Success = False then
    Num := Random(G);
    Time := 0;
end if;
end loop;

end Youngster;

task body DarkSide is
Num: RandNum;
Success: Boolean := False;
Time: Natural := 0;
begin
delay 2.0;
Reset(G);

loop
    Num := Random(G);

    if Collector.HowManyGuards = 0 and Collector.HowManyArrested /= DarkNum then
        Place.Vote(Num, True);
        delay 2.0;
    else
        Collector.Arrest;
        Put_Line("!!! L E A T A R T Ă“ Z T A T Ă S !!!");
        exit;
    end if;
end loop;

end DarkSide;

protected body Collector is
procedure GoHome is
begin
    Home := Home + 1;
end GoHome;

procedure GuardOut is
begin
    Guards := Guards - 1;
end GuardOut;

procedure GuardIn is
begin
    Guards := Guards + 1;
end GuardIn;

procedure Arrest is
begin
    Arrested := Arrested + 1;
end Arrest;

function HowManyArrested return Natural is
begin
    return Arrested;
end HowManyArrested;

function HowManyGuards return Natural is
begin
    return Guards;
end HowManyGuards;

function HowMany return Integer is
begin
    return Home;
end HowMany;
end Collector;

task body Guard is
Num: RandNum;
begin
Reset(G);
while Collector.HowMany /= YoungsterNum  and Collector.HowManyArrested /= DarkNum loop
    Num := Random(G);
    if Collector.HowManyGuards = 2 then
        if Num <= 30 then
            Collector.GuardOut;
            Put_Line("(((Ĺr kiment szabĂˇlyosan!)))");
            delay 10.0;
            Collector.GuardIn;
            Put_Line("(((Ĺr visszatĂ©rt!)))");
            delay 4.0;
        end if;
    else
        if Num <= 25 then
            Collector.GuardOut;
            Put_Line("(((Ĺr kiment szabĂˇlytalanul!)))");
            delay 10.0;
            Collector.GuardIn;
            Put_Line("(((Ĺr visszatĂ©rt!)))");
            delay 4.0;
        end if;
    end if;
end loop;
end Guard;

Youngsters: array (1..YoungsterNum) of Youngster;
Dark: array(1..DarkNum) of DarkSide;

begin
null;
end Election;
```

The put_lines are in hungarian, it doesn't matter. So what I'd like to do is when this is true:

```
if (Votes-(YoungsterNum + DarkNum)) > ((YoungsterNum + DarkNum) / 20) then
```

then I want all of these to start again:

```
Youngsters: array (1..YoungsterNum) of Youngster;
Dark: array(1..DarkNum) of DarkSide;
task Place is
entry Vote(Num: in RandNum; Cheat: in Boolean);
end Place;
```

And of course the two Guards in Place, that goes without saying. I hope this is clear.

Comment: This description is rather vague, as a solution would depend on how the electoral functionality within the tasks is implemented. Expand your question to describe the structure of what's happening in the task, and then some suggestions could be offered.  It's certainly possible to "reset" a task if it's implemented to permit that.

Comment: Any reason not to add a "Restart" entry to each task which sets it to its initial state?

Comment: Because the tasks don't finish their jobs at the same time, but when restarting the simulation they need to start together (kind of). If I was to add a Restart entry to each task it would result in some tasks working with incorrect data because others have already changed them. The answer I found is fundamentally different but it also has to do something with an entry. I'll post it as the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer which deals with the problem and also elegant enough to share, I think. I won't post code here, just the essentials:

1. Create a protected object.
2. Add a guarded entry to it. The entry should only allow calls when every task is finished with their job.
3. From each task, when they're ready to start again simulation, call this entry. Since there's a guard no task will be served until every task has called this guarded entry. (I checked this with a simple Natural counter variable inside the protected unit's private part.)
4. So when the last task joins the queue waiting for the entry, it allows them one-by-one, to "get through".
5. Inside the entry if you want to change variables used by more than one task, you should do it within an if statement with the condition "has the last task's call already been executed". This is needed because the entry serves the tasks one after another, so when the first is done, and you change important variables (e.g. something regarding the guard statement) the other tasks may wait in the queue infinitely.

I hope I've been clear. I think this is something called cyclic barrier in other languages.

Comment: A minor improvement on step 5 would be to have variables that are used by more than one task be inside a _protected type_ themselves.

Comment: @NWS They are inside the same protected object as the guarded entry, but that doesn't change a thing, I think. What improvement did you think of exactly?

Comment: Ive just reread your answer. My mistake - I Confused a _protected object_ and a _protected task_ which are the same thing!.

Comment: @NWS To my knowledge, a protected object is not a task, but a unit that encapsulated data items and provides access to them via subprograms and entries.

Comment: Exactly, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If the electoral task is currently just an election simulation wrapped in a task so that the multiple elections can proceed in parallel:

```
-- Not compiled
task body Simulated_Elections is

begin
   Initialize_Electoral_Information;
   Determine_Candidates;
   Run_Election;
   Inaugurate;
end Simulated_Elections;
```

Then just putting the functionality in a loop with an exit could suffice:

```
-- Still not compiled
task body Simulated_Elections is

begin
   loop
      select
         accept The_Voice_Of_The_People;
      or
         accept Tyranny_And_Dictatorship;
         exit;
      or
         terminate;
      end select;

      Initialize_Electoral_Information;
      Determine_Candidates;
      Run_Election;
      Inaugurate;
   end loop;
end Simulated_Elections;
```